# HTML5 game <-> server

Tags: php, javascript, sockets, client

I have:

1. PHP Socket Server
2. PHP Pages to handle communication with server & db
3. Client .php page, which uses javascript/canvas to display & interact with a game.

What I want is for the user to connect and authenticate using the PHP pages which will initiate a socket connection to the server. Based on the information from that socket some chat info and events might be triggered to load data into client php page.

What is the right way to handle this. In all instances that I've ajax in before, the user triggers the event, not the server and javascript waits around for the php page's response.

What piece of php code from the php socket lets me send messages to the canvas elements?

Here's an example as the above is probably not very illuminating:

IE:
PHP reads off of its socket connection `{"name":"msg","from":"user1","time":12345,"msg","hello world"}`

At this point what does PHP do?** So that ...

The client has a div with `"id='Incoming'"`

I want to launch the following javascript:

```
function handleMessage(msgObj) {
  var cText = document.getElementById("Incoming").innerHTML;
  cText += "(" + msgObj.time + ")" + msgObj.from + " says: " + msgObj.msg +"<br/>";
  document.getElementById("Incoming").innerHTML = cText;
}
```

I guess I'm trying to figure out how a client's web page is supposed to talk back to the php sockets...

Is this possible or do I need to make a client in flash, java, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send stuff from client to server when you've got data to send (e.g. user submits a button) typically via an event handler. The websocket also fires event when it receives data from the server (socket.onmessage). Simples.

```
ws.onmessage=function (evt) { handleMessage(evt.data); };
```

(or just change your handleMessage function body to use msgObj.data as the text value)

> What piece of php code from the php socket lets me send messages to the canvas elements?

What websocket implementation are you using? They all have different APIs (NB a websocket is not the same thing as a network socket)

Comment: I was looking at this:http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php | so, I think you are talking about websockets which might be a better way to do this? :/ Any documentation, anywhere?

Comment: You can't use network sockets from Javascript. Websockets are only supported in recent browsers (HTML5). Websockets are not implemented natively in PHP - have a google for PHP and websockets. I'd assumed you understood all this - if not then COMET miht be a more sensible approach - but you're going to have to learn a lot about persistent connections voer HTTP regardless of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Comet:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

AJAX is much better and also asynchronous

http://www.ape-project.org/
http://www.stream-hub.com/
...

http://cometdaily.com/maturity.html

or use HTML5 WebSockets

Comment: Why? The only type of "socket" which can be opened and manipulated using javascript *is* a websocket.

Comment: comet looks too error prone and like its going to be a headache to use; I'm trying to avoid the installation of any servers and just use already installed services...

Comment: then why not html5 web sockets using javascript directly or AJAX? well the javascript / ajax approach doesnt block the whole app and is much faster and asynchronous - so why not?  well but its different hen php sockets, html web sockets and so on